# My Django Project now won't run Python3 manage.py runserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, terminal, importerror

So I seen this issue here on stack, but for a few slightly different reasons and I can't manage to figure it out for myself.

I'm getting this error in my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

and YES i do have `django` installed.

I'm currently working on the Harvard CS50W project and it was working perfectly fine until i updated my python through HomeBrew.

Now my project can't locate `django` to run the server.
I seen stuff online about the `virtualenv` but I didn't need to set one up prior to starting this project. So I'm not sure what to do in order to get my project back up and running.

If someone could please help that would be great!

Thanks!

*Also should mention I'm using the M1 Mac. Just incase that makes a difference.*

Comment: You now have multiple Python installations.  You have to make sure you have installed into the same python you're running.  Instead of "pip3", try `python3 -m pip install django`.

Comment: Homebrew won't update the Python interpreter that the operating system uses. It will install a new one.

Comment: Check if multiple versions of python installed in your system...??

Comment: @TimRoberts I just tried that and it started to download then it said EnvironmentError:[Errno 13] Permisson denied: ‘/Library/Python/3.8’

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha how can I check how many python versions are installed?

Comment: @Selcuk what does that mean? Do I need to update the mac version of python?

Comment: You can't update the Mac version of Python.  There are system services from Apple that depend on it.  You need to do a little exploration to take inventory.  You probably have /usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python3 and /usr/local/bin/python and /usr/local/bin/python3.  Run them all by hand so you know what versions they are.  Run `which python3` to see which version you get by default.  Run `which pip3` to see if it comes from the same directory.  It's a mess, but you can straighten it out.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok thank you. I think its all because my initial install of brew was on rosetta2. I feel like that's what messed up my system.